# Create folder directory from path?

Tags: powershell, directory, powershell-2.0

I currently have a large list of folder paths that I want to use Powershell to create programatically. However my knowledge of Powershell, while growing, is still small.

E.G. - The given path is:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4
```

I want to physically create this folder path using Powershell. Not all of the file paths have the same amount of levels.

I get the basic concepts of reading the contents of the text file and making a directory:

```
get-content c:\folderPaths.txt | Foreach-Object{
     MD newFolder
}
```

However I am not sure how I can parse the Folder path to get each level of the new directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `-force` param, you can create all the folder in the tree in one action.

```
New-Item -ItemType directory C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4 -Force
```

`md` is the alias to the function `mkdir` that call `New-Item` CmdLet.

Comment: So lets say, my second directory I want to create is C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder102938. Would something like this work, since the original 3 levels have already been created?

Comment: @Johnrad, it is a very easy test, and the answer is: yes. An internal folder will be created *even* if the rest of the path exists.